# how to modify the program to find how long till the population doubled

Tags: matlab

```
p=malt(p0,r,n)

p=zeros(n+1,1);

p(1)=p0;

for i=1:n

    p(i+1)=(1+r)*p(i);
end
```

I wrote this program (in matlab) to find the population where,
p0=initial population, r=annual growth rate, n=years. I want to modify the code using while loop to be able to find how long till the population doubled.

Comment: any ideas on how to modify my program?.

Comment: What is p = malt(p0,r,n)?

Comment: p=malt(initial,growth rate, years). for Malthusian growth

Comment: But why do you use this if on the next line you set it to zero?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a while-loop:

```
p0 = 10000; 
r = 0.02;  % 0.02 --> 2%
p = cell(2,1);
p{1}=p0;
i = 1;

while (p{i}<p0*2)

    i = i + 1;
    p{i}=(1+r)*p{i-1};

end

years = i - 1;
```

But do you know that you don't need a loop for this but just a simple formula?

`Pn = P0*(1+r/100)^n`   with **n** in years and **r** the growth rate in percentage

If Pn needs to be 2*P0

```
--> n_doubling = log(2)/log(1+r/100)
```

Comment: so how can you write a program (in your simple formula) to find how long till the population doubles if initial population and annual growth rate are given

Comment: Exactly like I wrote it: `n_doubling = log(2)/log(1+r/100)` (r in percentage). To know the doubling time, you only need to know the growth rate, not the initial population. This is true for any kind of doubling question. Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_time

Comment: I tried it and it worked. but for the 'while loop' code you mentioned earlier did not work. there was some error with cell(2,1), which is not clear what does it mean. I am asked to adjust my coding using while loop to find how long the US population doubles from a certain year.

Comment: Which error do you get? Did you add a value for P0 and r? Cause that one you still need to fill in. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Alqosh Hazkeal Did you find what the problem was?

Comment: No, I keep getting Error ( Cell contents indices must be greater than 0
) in line where i put: while (p{0}<2*p0)

Comment: That is because the indices need to be greater than 0, so p{0} is not valid. That is why I put `while (p{i}<p0*2)` with `i=1`.